# Odoo filter order_line records on sale order form on custom property on product

Tags: python, filter, odoo

I have a custom Boolean property on product named 'emptygoods'. Now I'd like to filter the order lines on an sale order form to only show the lines where the emptygoods is set to False for there product. I tried using domain attribute on order_line but without success. It seems nothing inserted in the domain is doing a thing (tried numerous variants).

```
 <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="domain">[('product_id.emptygoods', '=', True)]</attribute>
 </xpath>
```

product.py models file:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
```

class product_template_inherit(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

```
emptygoods = fields.Boolean("Is empty goods")
```

Comment: Could u post your models.py file please ? It seems to me you use the field emptygoods on another model (order_line) as the one it belongs to (product)

Comment: Screenshot was incorrect, see updated code

Comment: Could u post your models.py file please ?